# Modify or hook into Jupyter's tab completion

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, tab-completion, jupyter-lab

I was wondering if there was a way to modify Jupyter Lab or Notebook's tab-complete functionality.  For example, if I type "\alpha", and then press the tab key, I will get the UTF-8 character "α" in the cell.

Is there any way that I can do a custom "[string without spaces]" to tab-complete into some specific UTF-8 character or string?

e.g. "\implies" + tab -> "⇒"

I can see a large number of use cases for this in my programming life, so I was wondering if Jupyter (Lab or Notebook) offered the ability to modify some settings (or load in a file) that maps strings to a tabbed output.  Or is there a different idea that you could use to implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jupyter is (based on) IPython and it's completion engine - we can make use of it.

**Update**: you can override `latex_symbols` dict to get the behavior you want:

```
from IPython.core.latex_symbols import latex_symbols
latex_symbols['\\implies'] = '⇒'
```

You should be able to build upon this example to make it work with a whole range of characters.

**Initial answer**/another solution: you can hook into IPython completers, though it would not work exactly as you wish: it won't replace the text, but just append a special character. Here is an example:

```
from IPython import get_ipython

def implies_competer(ipython, event):
    return ['⇒']

ipython = get_ipython()
ipython.set_hook('complete_command', implies_competer, re_key='.*implies')
```

Then when you type (the space after the keyword is important):
[image]

and then press `tab`, you will get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  That's helpful.  But how then does Jupyter allow for \alpha to become the unicode alpha character after tab completion?  Surely there's a way to delete the previous text, no?

Comment: Yes, there is. You were right with the idea of taking advantage of the existing mechanism, which is there for \alpha (and other latex symbols). I updated my answer.

Comment: @krassowski, Why is the space important and do you know a way to allow for completions without the space? Thanks.

Comment: @tmthyjames Just to make sure - have you tried the other way I provided in my edit to the answer)? It works without space (sorry I did not make it very clear back then).