# Keyboard shortcut to expand code snippets in JupyterLab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

Does anyone know how to make a shortcut that would paste a certain code to the selected cell or expand a snippet into a chunk of code?
For example I would like to fill a cell with a list of useful imports when pressing something like `Ctrl+Shift+M`. This would expand the cell content to:
`import numpy as np 
 import pandas as pd 
(...) .`

Optionally this could work also like text completion tools available in some IDEs. For example when I write something like:
`;imp + TAB` .

it would expand into the same list as above.

Any ideas how this could be defined in JupyterLab?

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49440087/map-keyboard-shortcut-to-code-snippet-in-jupyter-lab) answer, but it does not work for me (returning javascript error)

Comment: What's the javascript error you have ?

Comment: Very vague - I've just added a comment in the linked post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JupyterLab 2.1+ you can add a shortcut to insert a snippet using the following settings:

```json
{
    "shortcuts": [
        {
            "command": "apputils:run-first-enabled",
            "selector": "body",
            "keys": ["Accel Shift M"],
            "args": {
                "commands": [
                    "console:replace-selection",
                    "fileeditor:replace-selection",
                    "notebook:replace-selection",
                ],
                "args": {"text": "import numpy as np\nimport pandas as pd\n"}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

For more detailed instruction see my [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67149446/6646912) to the question you linked.

Another option is to use one of the code snippet extensions for JupyterLab:

- [jupyterlab-code-snippets](https://github.com/jupytercalpoly/jupyterlab-code-snippets) from CalPoly
- [jupyterlab-snippets](https://github.com/QuantStack/jupyterlab-snippets) from QuantStack
- [elyra-code-snippet-extension](https://elyra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/code-snippets.html) from Elyra IBM team (with multiple contributions from the CalPoly team)

Answer (score 0):

For emmet-style expansion of snippets in IPython, you can use:

```py
from IPython import get_ipython

def import_completer(ipython, event):
    return [
        'import numpy as np\nimport pandas as pd\n',
        'import tensorflow as tf\nimport autokeras as ak\n'
    ]

ipython = get_ipython()
ipython.set_hook('complete_command', import_completer, re_key='.*imp')
```

[image: demo]

Comment: There is also a special case for completing mathematical symbols in IPython: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50647764/6646912